# PayPal Express Review Order Page In Magento - Where I can edit code for design layout

Tags: magento, express, paypal, review

My magento template is forcing me to have a final REVIEW ORDER page when checking out.  I want to be able to edit the design of that page, but I cannot find what file the code is in. UGGH.  Can someone help me?  See screenshot.

I want to be able to change the font size of the words "REVIEW ORDER" to make it stand out more.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are looking for resides on

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/review.phtml

But before making changes to it,its good practice of overwriting it to you theme and making changes there.

Hope, this is what you are looking for.